# Change color of horizontal lines for class 'table table-condensed' in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to change the color of the horizontal lines in a bootstrap table having class `table-condensed` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are using `border-bottom` property for `td` and `th` - [Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).. so the selector you can use is

```
.table.table-condensed tr th {
   border-bottom: 2px solid #f00; /* Change the color you want to set */
}

.table.table-condensed tr td {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #f00; /* Change the color you want to set */
}
```

This will apply to all the tables, so it would be better if you assign a unique `class` or an `id` and change the selector accordingly.

---

If you want, you can also customize your Bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

Answer (score 3):

Do the following - lets say you want to make the horizontal lines red :

```js
/* header */
.table > thead > tr > th {
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
/* rows */
.table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
   border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/XazR4/**

Comment: Looks like the same as Mr. Alien's answer but as a newbie in html I don't understand how to put the code you propose.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the answers are same, though this is more than specific, which in your case wasn't required so even this is fine if specificity is the issue, else my selectors are more than enough, but if you want, it's better to customize the bootstrap at first place..

Comment: The only difference between mine and Mr Aliens CSS is, that mine covers every possible scenario, tfoots and so on. There is no difference in use, what should that be?

Comment: @Mr Alien - agree, I also believe your answer cover the needs. But it was hard to know, there was very poor specification in the question :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I voted you :) and yea I agree that's why I shared the general selector very first :) cuz I expect that he can apply the same logic to `th` and for `tfoot` we always use `td` so I didn't used that selector :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Ok thank you. This is the first time I see a syntax such as `.table > thead > tr > th`, that's why I was puzzled.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, it means "immediate children", effects the next children, but not the third and so on. Agree with Mr Alien, it is overkill. Not really nessecary. I was about to delete the answer, but now you both get a reverse upvote too :)

Comment: @davidkonrad keep it, don't delete, and also, it's not immediate children, we can say *direct children* :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your table like `<table class='table-condensed your_class'></table>`
and in your css add

```
table.your_class {
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Change red to whatever color you want.

Comment: This makes a border around the **table**, not horizontal lines for `thead`, `th`, `tr`, `td` and `tfoot`.

Comment: `table.your_class tr {}` `table.your_class tr td {}` `table.your_class thead {}` try these combos.it will work.